# Are any 4 linearly independent matrices in M2,2 a basis for M2,2 (like how any 2 linearly independent vectors in R2 are a basis for R2)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Are any 4 linearly independent matrices in $M_{2,2}$ a basis for $M_{2,2}$ similar to how if you have n linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, you have a basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Any four LI vectors in a four dimensional space form a basis.

Comment: If you aren't going to multiply the matrices with one another, there is essentially no difference between $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ and $\Bbb R^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In fact, there's an obvious linear isomorphism between $M_{2,2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$. Just think of your matrices as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (each entry of the matrix becomes an entry of the corresponding vector $\mathbb{R}^4$).